# Bilateral z transform in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I implement the bilateral z transform in MATLAB? The built-in function [ztrans](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ztrans.html) concerns only the unilateral z transform.

Answer (score 1):

The bilateral transform can be obtained from two unilateral transforms. Suppose f is the function to be transformed. Then `ztrans` gives the sum of f(n)z<sup>-n</sup> over n=0,1,2,... Introduce the new function g(n) = f(-n-1) and apply `ztrans` to it: the result is the sum of f(-n-1)z<sup>-n</sup> over n=0,1,2,... Relabeling -n-1 as new index k, we get the sum of f(k)z<sup>k+1</sup> over negative integers k. Divide this by z and replace z by 1/z: then the result is the sum of f(k)z<sup>-k</sup> over negative integers k, which is precisely the missing part of the bilateral transform. In code it could look like

```
syms n z
f = sin(n);
T1 = ztrans(f, n, z);
T2 = ztrans(subs(f, n, -n-1), k, z);
B = T1 + subs(T2/z, z, 1/z);
```

where B is now the bilateral transform.

Comment: NB: code is not tested as I don't have the symbolic toolbox.

Comment: Hi @Michelle. I tried your code with the sequence x[n]=-a^n*heaviside(-n-1), but it does not work. The code is the following: close all
clear all
syms n z k a
assume(a > 0)
assumeAlso(a < 1)
assumeAlso(a > z)
f = -a^n;
T1 = ztrans(f, n, z);
T2 = ztrans(subs(f, n, -n-1), k, z);
B = T1 + subs(T2/z, z, 1/z). The result is -heaviside(n)/(a^(n + 1)*(1/z - 1)) instead of z/(z-a).

Comment: Sorry the function is f=-a^n*heaviside(-n-1);

Comment: Hi @Michelle. The correct result of the above sequence is z/(z-a). Have you any brainstorms on how can I get it? See http://www.iet.unipi.it/m.greco/esami_lab/bio/Trasformate%20zeta%20notevoli.pdf please.

Comment: Its a recursive filter. Look up IIR (Infinite Impulse Response). To understand it you have to really, learn complex numbers move on to la-place transforms and then go into the digital Z transform world.

Comment: Its a recursive filter. Look up IIR (Infinite Impulse Response). To understand it you have to really, learn complex numbers move on to la-place transforms and then go into the digital Z transform world. This book https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234789949_First_Principles_of_Discrete_Systems_and_Digital_Signal_Processing was very helpful to me back in 1987