# How can I display z transform of u(-n-1) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

where u(n) is the unit step function
u(n)=
1,n>=0
0, otherwise

The answer should be same as as that of u(n) but in Matlab it shows 0.
Here is my code:

```
clc;
clear all;
syms n;
oldparam=sympref('HeavisideAtOrigin',1);
x=heaviside(-n-1);
ztrans(x)
```

Comment: Matlab computes the _unilateral_ _z_-transform (see the [documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.ztrans.html#d124e328822)). The function `u(-n-1)` is `0` for all `n >= 0`, so its unilateral _z_-transform is `0`

Comment: Isn't there any way to compute bilateral z-transform?

Comment: You can define it manually: `symsum(x*z^-n, n, -inf, inf)`. Or maybe decompose as the sum of two unilateral transforms and use `ztrans`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45661969/2586922